# Not able to see editor preview when I click "show preview"

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, editor, inline-editor

While I am editing a post (mine or posted by some one other), I cannot see a *preview of the markdown*. This makes me uncomfortable that I might break the formatting of the post.

**Update**: After the comments, I figured out there is a link to see the preview, but I am not able to see it.

1. Try to edit a question.
2. Now, click on "Show preview"
3. I do not see the preview.

Browser: Firefox 7.0.1

1. A 15sec [screencast](http://www.screenr.com/beZs) of the problem
2. On firebug console:

   `assignment to undeclared variable preview

   http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=6a19ff0e57e3
   Line 1`

Comment: You can't break the formatting of another question. Have you tried upgrading browsers?

Comment: Why can't I? Say I am editing some one else's question after they have posted, I edit it. Now, before saving, I should see a preview of the changes. I.e. the way it used to work earlier.

Comment: What's your browser and have you flushed the cache?

Comment: I dont get it. Why is my browser a problem here? I use firefox 7.0. My suggestion is to enable to preview of a post while you are editing it. On stackoverflow, it's disabled.

Comment: There should be a preview - immediately below the edit box. The browser might be relevant if there's a bug preventing the preview from appearing.

Comment: 1. Ahh, ic. There is a button for: show preview, but nothing happens when I click it. I will add a bug tag with this question.
2. Can the downvoter please explain the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I think people thought you were worried about breaking *another* question - not the one you were editing. For what it's worth I see a link "hide preview" which doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I can confirm something is weird with the hide preview button ... probably my class change last week ... will correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last week we enabled [strict mode](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) in all our JavaScript files, unfortunately we missed one spot where we (me) forgot to declare a `var`.

Fixed it, for the record, option strict rules.