# Comment name autocomplete moves cursor

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, comment-replies, autocomplete

I revise pretty much everything I write before I publish/post/send it. When I write comments, I sometimes have to move `@name` notifications around as a result of other edits. However, using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> name autocomplete automatically moves the text cursor to the end of the comment, which isn't the behavior I expect. I'd like for the cursor to appear at the end of the name so that I can keep typing as if I'd just typed the name in manually.

(In case this isn't happening to everyone: FF5/Win7 and FF7/Win7)

Comment: +1 - Happening to me too on Chrome/WinXP

Comment: I see this on Safari 5.1.1/mac OS X 10.7.2. In my case, moving the cursor to the end of the comment was welcome, as I was writing the comment, and noticed I didn't use the @-reference; I added it, and I continued to edit the comment (the cursor was moved where I wanted it to be).

Answer (score 4):

Reasonable expectation – in particular because that's what happens in chat, and *used* to happen here as well.

The explanation of this bug is identical to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111288/not-able-to-see-editor-preview-when-i-click-show-preview/111337#111337). Fixed in the next build.