# Why am I not able to see preview sometimes?

Tags: support, markdown-preview, inline-editor

Why am I not able to see preview sometimes on some posts while I can see preview on other post at the same time?

For e.g. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18588591/1369235)

I am not able to see preview in inline edit even after I refreshed the page.

> [image]

I tried to ask the question before but the issue went away while asking the question so I ignored, but this happened again so just want to know the reason behind it.

Related: [Not able to see editor preview when I click "show preview"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111288/187824) but it was resolved.

Google Chrome (v 29.0.1547.62 m), Windows XP

Comment: Any JavaScript errors? Network errors?

Comment: @Oded - Can't say now as I can see the preview again :(

Comment: Understood. Without something to point at, a way to repro... not much we can do to follow up on this :(

Comment: @Oded - Yeah that's why I didn't add a `bug` tag.

Comment: It's still a bug, regardless of whether or not it's reproduceable. Everyone who gets this should probably provide as much as possible possibly useful information about their OS, browser, network, browser add-ons and applicable apps (e.g. firewall?).